# Do i have to wrap GSAP in angular animate?

Tags: angularjs, animation, gsap

I am building an Angular web app and I cannot get GSAP integrated. I have tried a bunch of hacks to no avail. My question is ...do i have to wrap GSAP in angular animate or can i just directly use GSAP to animate stuff in a angular controller?

When I run the app I do not get errors and all the script are loaded, but nothing happens.

All the examples i see are wrapping the Greensock library in Angular animate.

Does Angular animate even work in IE8? I just want to rotate a div on click. Can i do this with JQuery?

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?